# Form creation Error after server checkpoint passed

Tags: forms, creation, checkpoint

I'm making a server checkpoint in my new version for this app. and I'm encountering this error
when my app tries to open my main form.

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for
>   details.  The error is: ActiveX control
>   '6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6' cannot be instantiated because
>   the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

I'm not sure what this is, because it's something like a usual form except this form is used as Splash screen. When I remove the splash screen the form opens normally with all plugins and modules.
Here's a part of the code I used

```
Public Class example_form
    Public Function servercheck() As Boolean
        Dim objUrl As New System.Uri("http://google.com")
        Dim objWebReq As System.Net.WebRequest
        objWebReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(objUrl)
        Dim objresp As System.Net.WebResponse

        Try
            objresp = objWebReq.GetResponse
            objresp.Close()
            objresp = Nothing
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            objresp = Nothing
            objWebReq = Nothing
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function


    Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        If servercheck() = True Then
            Form1.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        Else : PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._12383u9
            MsgBox("some text here", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now you have the code. The error is on the background worker when it tries to open the form. (at the end of the code)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found what is the error. For those who have this error, do not add the form.show() command in the backgroundworker in work mode. the form should be load when backgroundworker will finish. so the correct code is like this

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
              If servercheck() = True Then
            Me.Hide()
            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        Else : PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._12383u9
            MsgBox("Some text here", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub
```